# Jenkins slave is unable to checkout from subversion

Tags: svn, jenkins

Jenkins slave is unable to checkout the code from subversion and its throwing below message, while the master is able to checkout the code.

Checking out https://svn.myorg.com/svn/ProjectName at revision '2016-04-26T02:41:04.278 -0400'
ERROR: Failed to check out  https://svn.myorg.com/svn/ProjectName
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: timed out waiting for server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Jenkins version - 1.640
subversion plugin - 2.5.7

subversion version on both master & slave VMs - 
 svn --version
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
   compiled Aug  4 2015, 09:07:02

I tried to checkout the code locally on the slave VM but still the same issue - could not connect to server https://svn.myorg.com/svn ......

svnkit on master is svnkit-1.8.11.jar

Any ideas how to counter it ?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many details about your issue, so I could only guess:

1. Are you behind a cooperate proxy server? if so make sure your proxy is defined properly on the slave. check connectivity on the slave to see if you can access the internet.
2. What kind of security you have on the slave? maybe a firewall is blocking your network? try installing [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to check your connection to the server on the machine.

if you can provide any other details about your situation it'll be much more helpful for us to answer your question. Hope it helps a bit!